# Not sure about using test command with al in assembly

Tags: assembly

I am new to assembly and have begun to learn it through an assignment. However, I am not so sure about using the "test" command:

The first command is "anding" together the constant 1 and eax. If eax is something like 10101010 and 1 is: 00000001, then "anding" them together would produce: 0. But what does testing the lowest four bits of the register have to do with anything - and why is it important? What is this entire expression doing?

```
8049ac0:       83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax // "and" these bits together
8049ac3:       84 c0                   test   %al,%al  // check the last 
8049ac5:       74 05                   je     8049acc <level_4+0x60> // if it is equal, then skip down.
```

Comment: `AL` contains the lowest **8** bits of `EAX`. The explicit test may be necessary because the remaining 24(!) bits in `EAX` can be anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` instruction is actually redundant, so doesn't do anything useful.  It probably comes about because the compiler that produced this code is not very good at optimizing, so included an unnecessary instruction that doesn't hurt anything.

```
and  $1,%eax    ; clear all bits of %eax except the lowest, set ZF if all bits are now zero
test %al,%al    ; set ZF if %al (the lowest 8 bits of %eax) are all clear
je   somewhere  ; branch if ZF is set
```

So the `and` instruction will set the ZF flag equal to the complement of the lowest bit of %eax, and the `test` instruction will set it again to the same thing.  This probably comes from code that looks like:

```
if (var&1) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

where it loads `var` into `%eax` just before your code snip, and the branch target is just after the `}`.  The code that is generated first computes `var & 1` into a temp register (the `and` instruction), then tests to see if the result is non-zero (the `test` instruction), then branches over the `...do something...` if the test was false (the `je` instruction).

Answer (score 0):

`and $0x1,%eax` leaves **one** bit of `EAX` untouched: the rightmost or least significant one. If this bit is set, then `EAX` was odd, in the other case it was even. `test %al,%al` (the least significant 8 bits of `EAX`) actually sets the zero-flag accordingly to that bit. Z=1 (jz/je jumps) means that `EAX` was even.

Comment: This actually was actually a huge key to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The register are named, for example:

- 8bits lowest                       ->  AL
- 8bits highest of the 16bits lowest ->  AH
- 16bits                             ->  AX
- 32bits                             -> EAX

  ```
             --AH-- --AL-- 8bits each.
             -----AX------ 16bits
  ```

  `---------EAX------------ 32bits`

In [x86 Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) is a more detail explanation of CPU registers and pictures of then to better understand

In your case you are clearing all the bits of EAX (32bits register) except the lowest and testing the 8 lowest bits of EAX (AL). The [`test` instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)) will perform a `Bitwise AND` and update the cpu flags accordingly, this flags will be used by `je` (jump if equal, that test for the Zero Flag). In this case is checking if the lowest 8 bits of EAX are 0 or not, if they are, jump to the address indicate in the jump.